# In a .desktop file, what is the "%U" variable?

Tags: xdg

Or, more generally, what is the syntax of the commands such as `exo-open --launch WebBrowser %u` ?

Comment: Please note that in the title you're asking about `%U` while in the command it says `%u`. These codes are actually case sensitive as described in [the docs](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html). The former is a list of URLs while the latter is a single URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the various % (percent)-parameters in context-menu actions or .desktop files mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783292/what-do-the-various-percent-parameters-in-context-menu-actions-or-desktop-f)

Answer (score 28):

When the program is launched the file manager or program launcher will expand the `%u` with a single URL or file path of the thing you are trying to open.

See the [Freedesktop.org Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html) for other codes that you can use in a .desktop file.

Answer (score 13):

From  [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles):

> Notice the %U used in the .desktop file above. It is used so as the application to be able to accept an argument when dragging and dropping a file inside the Unity bar on the left. Without it, the program will launch itself, but the argument will not be passed to it and it will be just the same as clicking the application so as to launch.

Answer (score 4):

> In a .desktop file, what is the “%U” variable?

That is called an **`Exec` key code**, which is listed [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html) and discussed with more details in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301577/from-digikam-to-whatsapp/1319669#1319669).

---

> Or, more generally, what is the syntax of the commands such as `exo-open --launch WebBrowser %u` ?

That is a different matter and the use of an `Exec` key code in this case is both unneeded and has no effect.

It is not part of the expected arguments/parameters for [`exo-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/exo-open.1.html) and will be ignored in this case.

Unless it is used as a parameter / argument for `Exec` *in a `.desktop` file* like so:

```
Exec=exo-open --launch WebBrowser %u
```

and in both cases `%u` is out of the scope of `exo-open`.

Comment: What do you mean *"and in both cases `%u` is out of the scope of `exo-open`"*?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I mean in the second case `Exec=exo-open --launch WebBrowser %u` it is used as a parameter/argument for `Exec` and not `exo-open`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, those are the references I was confusingly looking for.

Comment: I have used a couple of these in the past, but didn't know what they were called so I could look them up. Thanks.